# Can this function be garbage-collected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection, v8

Consider this piece of cake... ehm, code:

```
'use strict'

function doWork () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    // work work work...
    // Done! But... where's the resolve() ???
  })
}

doWork().then(function doMoreWork () {
  // Some more work to do...
})
```

Once the function in the Promise's constructor finishes...

1. Is the `Promise` object garbage-collectible?
2. Is `doMoreWork()` garbage-collectible?

My guess is that `doMoreWork()` cannot be GC-ed directly because the Promise keeps a reference to it, but once the promise's body finishes and returns the execution context to the upper (?) scope, the stack unwinds (because there is no more statements here to be executed) and the Promise becomes unreachable, thus being garbage-collectible.

Can you confirm that my understanding of this topic is correct?

**How could I empirically observe this behaviour?** In other words, how can I monitor what objects are being GC-ed and when? I develop purely in Node.js, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Do you mean that your work never calls `resolve()`? Yes, in that case all your objects would be suspect to gc immediately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing keeping reference to the promise so it will be garbage collected. The promise is the only thing keeping reference to the function `doMoreWork` so it will be garbage collected too.

> How could I empirically observe this behaviour? In other words, how can I monitor what objects are being GC-ed and when? I develop purely in Node.js, if that makes any difference.

The GC in V8 never necessarily collects an object. For instance if this is your whole program, it would be a waste of time to run any GC in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `Promise` object is collectable if it has no references pointing to it.
   If it is used `doWork().then(...)` a temporary reference is created. So until      `.then` does not block anymore there is a reference to the object so it cannot be collected
2. You're right, `doMoreWork` is also not collectible because the `Promise`object has a reference to it

The statement `doWork().then(...)` can be replaced by

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  // work work work...
}).then(function doMoreWork () {
          // Some more work to do...
        })
```

So you can imagine that you are using the `Promise`object directly, so the "Upper"-Scope is where the object is used.

Objects are generally collected when there are no more references to it. Even if the code is in a Promise it is just an object and the call to `then` is chained, so the object is being used

Comment: I think Esailija's answer should be right, but it can't be proven without knowing the Promise implementation.  The Promise is created, a single .then() call is done on it, then, according to the code, it's unused so the promise and then the argument to then() can both be recycled.  But, what if your Promise implementation keeps some sort of internal list or table of Promises that are created?  Maybe it frees them when resolved; maybe never.  My guess is that they don't write Promise implementations that way; but there's no proof.  Either way, your JS program can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

To see if an object is garbage-collectible you can create a test and look for memory leak (through task manager). If your code is written properly, everything gets collected.

Comment: I think the main concern was not aboute memory leaks, but rather about the `doMoreWork` function code execution, is there a guarantee that it'll be executed? Because if it is GCed - it won't be.