# Dealing with forgotten promises in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

Here is an example that will hopefully make understaning the question easier.

```js
var listen = document.querySelector("#listen"),
  cancel = document.querySelector("#cancel"),
  submit = document.querySelector("#submit");

var promiseResolve = null;

listen.addEventListener("click", startListening);
cancel.addEventListener("click", abort);
submit.addEventListener("click", onSubmitClick);
submit.disabled = true;

function startListening() {
  submit.disabled = false;
  listen.disabled = true;
  new Promise(function(resolve) {
    promiseResolve = resolve;
  }).then(onSubmit);
}

function abort() {
  listen.disabled = false;
  submit.disabled = true;
  promiseResolve = null;
}

function onSubmitClick() {
  if (promiseResolve) promiseResolve();
}

function onSubmit() {
  console.log("Done");
  abort();
}
```

```html
<button id="listen">Listen</button>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

In the script above there is an action (`listen`) that will enable another action (`submit`), using the help of a `Promise`. But that flow can be cancelled using the `cancel` action, returning most of the code to its original state. The `cancel` action only sets the reference of the `resolve` of the `Promise` to null, meaning that the promise will forever stay in limbo as it will never be resolved or rejected. So these are my questions:

- Is this approach correct?
- Would doing this a large amount of times, occupy an equally large amount of resources?
- Should I also keep a reference to the reject function and call that in the `cancel` action?

I know in the example above the same result can be achieved by just
using a `boolean` flag to check if the listen button has been pressed
before the submit, but like I said this is just an example so that I
can more easily explain the question.

Comment: I believe in theory it should get GC'ed.  But it's using Promises for what they were not designed for.   To really get the benefits of promises it's best to think about how would you do this in a synchronous way, then write your code that way.  eg. You could make your startListening into a promise that you then place that in a loop, for abort I would generate a custom error, like `EAbort`.  There is often a lot of talk about cancel-able promises, but I'm not sure what state that is at.  I believe Google don't like the idea, it's maybe because a cancel-able promise is a bit like a task kill.

Comment: Looking at your code, you no longer have a reference, you did this ->  `promiseResolve = null;`   The GC works by looking at references, if a reference has no way to get back to the root / global, ps. Timers etc, are also global,.  Then the garbage collector will dispose.  The GC is even clever enough to GC `a = b; b = a`, This was a limitation of reference counted memory management like `interfaces` in C++ land.

Comment: @Keith I understand what you are saying, please check my comment on the answer to understand my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36735167/10949543) answer;

> Most code that uses promises expects them to resolve or reject at some
>   point in the future (that's why promises are used in the first place).
>   If they don't, then that code generally never gets to finish its work.
>
> It's possible that you could have some other code that finishes the
>   work for that task and the promise is just abandoned without ever
>   doing its thing. There's no internal problem in Javascript if you do
>   it that way, but it is not how promises were designed to work and is
>   generally not how the consumer of promises expect them to work.

Failing to resolve or reject a promise doesn't cause a problem in Javascript, but it's a bad practice anyway. Your application cannot determine what happened to the promise if it never resolves. Instead of leaving the promise in limbo, return a value like an error message, and have the promise filter results for an error message. If it finds an error, reject() the promise so the application can determine its next move.

```js
var listen = document.querySelector("#listen"),
  cancel = document.querySelector("#cancel"),
  submit = document.querySelector("#submit");

var promiseResolve = null;

listen.addEventListener("click", startListening);
cancel.addEventListener("click", onCancelClick);
submit.addEventListener("click", onSubmitClick);
submit.disabled = true;

function startListening() {
  submit.disabled = false;
  listen.disabled = true;
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    promiseResolve = (error) => {
       if (error) { reject(error); } else { resolve(); }
    };
  }).then(onSubmit)
  .catch(error => onError(error));
}

function abort() {
  listen.disabled = false;
  submit.disabled = true;
  promiseResolve = null;
}

function onSubmitClick() {
  if (promiseResolve) promiseResolve();
}

function onCancelClick() {
  if (promiseResolve) promiseResolve("Cancelled!");
}

function onSubmit() {
  console.log("Done");
  abort();
}

function onError(error) {
  console.warn(error);
  abort();
}
```

```html
<button id="listen">Listen</button>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: Why would the `Promise` get `garbagecollected`? I never actually kept a reference to the `Promise` itself, only the `resolve` function, which I don't believe references the Promise. If the `Promise` doesn't get garbage-collected when i had the reference to the function, why would there be any difference after losing a reference to an irrelevant object?

Comment: @nickzoum The garbage collector cleans objects when an object still exists, but no code has a reference remaining of that object, like when you call `myObject = null`. The GC can then safely reclaim the memory for that object because no code can ever reach that object again (even though it still technically exists before the GC is called). See also [this](https://javascript.info/garbage-collection) article.

Comment: You have basically answered you own question,..  `when i had the reference`,  That's the key part, if you don't have a reference to something in JS, that leads back to some form of global, it will get GC'ed.  That's why in JS you generally don't have to worry about these sort of things.  Saying that, it's still possible to get memory leaks,  but that's often by attaching to addEventListener, setIntervals etc, that you no longer require.  That's why they is clearInterval, removeEventListener etc.

Comment: @Keith I still feel like, you haven't fully understood my question. In the code in the question, I never keep a reference to the promise, does that mean that the promise will get garbagecollected even if I don't call the `cancel` action? If not why would the promise get garbagecollected after the `cancel` action?

Comment: @Robb216 I am accepting your answer as you've answered by question, but I would appreaciate it, if you could solve my query regarding the GC (unless if you think it would be a better idea to create a new question).

Comment: Because nothing will have a reference to the Promise.  Your promise initially had  reference to a function, inside that function was a resolve callback.   So you reference Links -> Promise - function - resolver,   so your Promise will get GC's, when all 3 have no reference to the global.  IOW: Look at this from another angle, what in you code do you think can get back to the global?  The only other thing attached to the Promise, is a thenable, but that's just `Promise -> then`, still no way back to the global.

Comment: @nickzoum [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29341683/10949543) question (and answer) seems to indicate that a promise without reference, and without any references to it's resolve or reject functions, are GC'ed. Since your code still has references to it's resolve function, it cannot be GC'ed. See also [this](https://dankuck.github.io/2017/02/24/broken-js-promises.html) article, especially the "References you forgot" section.

Comment: @Keith But neither the function nor the resolve callback have a property that references the promise. Does GC also check closures even if there is no reference through the properties?

Comment: It does have a reference,  `new Promise(fn)`,  The promise has a reference to fn.  `function (resolve, reject)`,  the function has a reference to `resolve` & `reject`.  But if nothing gets back to the gobal, it will get GC'ed.  eg. doing `new Promise((resolve, reject) => console.log("never going to happen"))`  will get freed, but if you assigned that to `window.dummy = ...`  it won't get GC's, until you did `window.dummy = null`, etc.

Comment: @Keith The promise has a reference to the function, but not the other way around, I said: `But neither the function nor the resolve callback have a property that references the promise`. Regardless the article Robb recommended solved my question.

Comment: `The promise has a reference to the function, but not the other way around,`  It doesn't need too.  Yes, that link gives some good info.

Comment: @nickzoum Yes, the `resolve` function references the promise object (or at least its internal state that includes the fulfill/reject handlers that might need to get called). It doesn't do this through a property, yes, but through closure (or some other internal reference, if promises are implemented in native code).

Comment: @Robb216 Don't make `promiseResolve` so complicated with the optional `error` parameter that gets checked. Instead, just do  `promiseResolve = resolve` like the OP did, and call `resolve(Promise.reject(…))` to reject it.