# Run asynchronous commands in a webpage with node.js / electron / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

EDIT: using `BrowserWindow`.

What the simplest/best way to launch javascript commands in a webpage one after the other ?  (asynchronous, not synchronous)
For example, several `document.write` triggered by a `keypress` event.

```
document.write("line 1");
wait_for_key_press();
document.write("line 2");
wait_for_key_press();
document.write("line 3");
wait_for_key_press();
document.write("line 4");
...

function wait_for_key_press(){
 ...
}
```

Comment: try alert or promt

Comment: If they're synchronous, that's automatic - they will inherently run one after the other. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: "one after the other ?" implies that you want [asynchronous](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/asynchronous)

Comment: you should await the `wait_for_key_press` call

Comment: sorry, edited, I meant the opposite :P

Comment: @bobdylan does the code need to be in this format? Is using `Promise` out of the question? for example: `do1(); wait().then(() => {do2(); do3();});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to wait for an action before a code is run is using promises or event listeners (or both). For example:

```js
var resolves = [];

document.querySelector("#start").addEventListener("click", doActions);
document.querySelector("#stop-wait").addEventListener("click", function() {
  resolves.forEach(function(resolve) {
    resolve();
  });
  resolves = [];
});

function waitButtonClick() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolves.push(resolve);
  });
}

function doActions() {
  console.log("Step 1");
  waitButtonClick().then(function() {
    console.log("Step 2");
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="start">Start Actions</button>
<button id="stop-wait">Stop waiting</button>
```

The same can be accomplished using `await` and `async`:

```js
var resolves = [];

document.querySelector("#start").addEventListener("click", doActions);
document.querySelector("#stop-wait").addEventListener("click", function() {
  resolves.forEach(function(resolve) {
    resolve();
  });
  resolves = [];
});

function waitButtonClick() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolves.push(resolve);
  });
}

async function doActions() {
  console.log("Step 1");
  await waitButtonClick();
  console.log("Step 2");
}
```

```html
<button id="start">Start Actions</button>
<button id="stop-wait">Stop waiting</button>
```

[`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Browser_compatibility) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) are only implemented in modern browsers and node (which should suit your case, since you are using electron). If you also want to support IE you could create a custom `Promise` polyfill:

```js
if (typeof window["Promise"] !== "function") {
  window["Promise"] = function(callBack) {
    var catchList = [];
    var thenList = [];
    this.then = function(callBack) {
      if (typeof callBack === "function") thenList.push(callBack);
      return this;
    };
    this.catch = function(callBack) {
      if (typeof callBack === "function") catchList.push(callBack);
      return this;
    };

    function resolve(result) {
      thenList.forEach(function(callBack) {
        callBack(result);
      });
    };

    function reject(error) {
      catchList.forEach(function(callBack) {
        callBack(error);
      });
    };
    callBack(resolve, reject);
  };
}
```

Comment: Amazing, i was able to adapt the one with await/async. Thanks !

Comment: Glad I could help @bobdylan . I also just updated my answer to also include what you should do if you need to implement something similar in IE or other old browsers

Comment: @bobdylan I think you should also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400611/dealing-with-forgotten-promises-in-javascript) regarding forgotten promises

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax. To wait for a keypress, add an event listener to the `keypress` event. In this example, line 2 gets printed when the user hits the enter key.

```js
async function myProgram() {
  console.log('line 1')
  await myAsyncFunction();
  console.log('line 2');
}
myProgram();

async function myAsyncFunction(){
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
  document.addEventListener('keypress', function _listener(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      document.removeEventListener('keypress', _listener);
      resolve();
    }
  });
 });
}
```

Comment: I actually need each lines to be triggered by a keypress (edited original post)